# EntityGraph or Join Fetch with Inheritance in JPA/Hibernate

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am working on JPA/Hibernate entities with JpaRepositories. I have few entities with `@OneToOne` and `@OneToMany` relationships. To make code short and simple I have named entities as A, B, C, D etc.. A is the root entity and below chain there is Inheritance with Joined strategy. Please look code below -

A.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "A")
public class A {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long aId;

    @Column
    private String name;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "bId")
    private B b;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "a")
    private Set<C> cSet;
    
    // other entity specific fields
    // getters and setters
}
```

B.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "B")
public class B {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long bId;

    // other entity specific fields
    // getters and setters
}
```

C.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "C")
public class C {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long cId;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "aId", referencedColumnName = "aId")
    private A a;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "c")
    private Set<D> dSet;

    // other entity specific fields
    // getters and setters
}
```

D.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "D")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class D {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long dId;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "cId", referencedColumnName = "cId")
    private C c;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "d")
    private Set<E> eSet;

    // other entity specific fields
    // getters and setters

}
```

E.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "E")
public class E {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long eId;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "dId", referencedColumnName = "dId")
    private D d;

    // other entity specific fields
    // getters and setters
}
```

F.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "F")
public class F extends D {

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "d")
    private Set<H> hSet;

    // other entity specific fields
    // getters and setters
}
```

G.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "G")
public class G extends D {

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "d")
    private Set<I> iSet;

    // other entity specific fields
    // getters and setters
}
```

H.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "H")
public class H {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long hId;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "dId", referencedColumnName = "dId")
    private D d;

    // other entity specific fields
    // getters and setters
}
```

I.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "I")
public class I {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long iId;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "dId", referencedColumnName = "dId")
    private D d;

    // other entity specific fields
    // getters and setters
}
```

If you see inheritance starts from entity D being parent, G and F extends D. I need to fetch all entities either by EnityGraph or Join fetch. All associations are lazy. I have id of the root A. I need to fetch complete data without n+1 queries for A (aId) when I call ... `aRepository.findById(aId);`

I tried many solutions but i am unable to fetch. The problem to create EntityGraph is the inheritance in between entities chain. The only way i was able to fetch was when I made associations EAGER. I don't want to make `@OneToMany` mappings as EAGER.

Can anyone suggest me a solution (either `@EntityGraph` or Join Fetch) to perform this task ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JPA inheritance @EntityGraph include optional associations of subclasses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61254061/jpa-inheritance-entitygraph-include-optional-associations-of-subclasses)

Answer (score 0):

this seems very similar to this question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61272573/412446

I think you can deduce that entity graphs can't be used for this. You could use join fetch though if you want, but I think Spring Data JPA repositories can only work with entity graphs. You can still use [Blaze-Persistence Entity-Views](https://persistence.blazebit.com/documentation/entity-view/manual/en_US/index.html#spring-data-features) though :)